# Group by improvements?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sybase-ase15

I have a requirement to improve below distinct slow query to use `group by`(or any other suggestion...)

```
insert into #temp1
    select distinct col1, '', 'known',col2, col3
    from mytable
```

Help please.

Index is only on `col1` which is int type. 
Rest of columns are varchar(10)

It's a Sybase query but any SQL compliant code would do(i.e. no CTE).
regards.

Comment: Hi, Welcome to Stack Overflow. I suggest checking out http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to help ask a better question.

Comment: Adding a compound index on `col1, col2, col3` would likely improve the query performance.

Comment: For a query as simple as that, distinct and group by should use the exact same execution plan...

Comment: using group by will have no effect on that query